# How do I specify a valid entry point / file for Vue projects?

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface

Came back to an old Vue project. Try to bring it up on my local machine using 'vue serve' and I got the following error.

How do I specify a valid entry point for vue projects?

Command:

```
vue serve
```

Terminal Error:

```
"Failed to locate entry file in /Users/$username/Desktop/my-project.
"Valid entry file should be one of: main.js, index.js, App.vue or app.vue.
```

Comment: Did you use `vue create ...` to start the project?

Answer (score 4):

```
vue serve src/main.js
```

Need to add the file to start from after the serve command

Answer (score 0):

**npm run serve**
need to type this command .

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this would be to specify the path to the main.js file in the package.json file as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vue serve src/main.js",
    "prod": "vue build src/main.js"
}
```

And then simply run

> npm run dev

for serving the project in the development environment and

> npm run prod

for creating a production build under dist folder